# How to do math formula in the sql query for desc sorting (res.a div res.b)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a large mySql table with user given finger up/down ratings. At the moment I have two basic sorting options for table to choose from:

```
 ['likes desc', 'id desc'],
 ['dislikes desc', 'id desc'],
```

I would like to add 3rd sorting option, that would convert above n/o of likes OR dislikes to one easy 1..5 star rating system with this kind of formula:

```
$rank = ($this->getLikes() / ($this->getDislikes() + $this->getLikes()))*5 ;
```

What is the highest performance option to do this math on sql level itself, would it be possible to do sorting for "result.likes div result.dislikes" formula inside the SQl query itself, or should I make a few queries to get a proper output somehow?  I dont want to make a third column for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just use it as a seperate column that contains this calculated rank and sort by the rank

Comment: Well I dont want to make a new column, instead I prefer to count it realtime with sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula directly in the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER BY
  (likes/(likes+dislikes))*5
```

If this is performant is up to you to check, this depends on many factors.

Comment: Thanks but for unknown reason this returned empty result set

Comment: the order by clause should not restrict the number of rows returned, could you post the whole query?

Comment: Sorry my typo,  it was OK!

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job, without a new column:

```
SELECT *, (likes/(likes+dislikes))*5 AS rank FROM tableName order by rank DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

So one thing i assume you can do is get the needed data by applying where clause and use it as tmp table and apply order by on this. Like below

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM products where name like '%bottle%') tmp ORDER BY (tmp.likes/(tmp.likes+tmp.dislikes))*5;
```

Comment: @NicoHaase, why I went with a temp table, is to avoid sorting of unwanted records. If ordering is applied without temp table, there is a case of full table scan can happen, in case of using temp table only filtered records will be ordered.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me, as this never makes sense. Why should ordering be done first on a query that contains a `WHERE` statement before this is evaluated? Can you give any reference?